# How to compute elapsed time between two dates in a CSV file using Python?

Tags: python, database, csv

How can I compute the elapsed time between two date using Python?

I try to do it using some methods found on GeeksForGeeks but I can't get it.

You can find my code here :

```
 import csv
 import pandas as pd
 from datetime import date

 data = pd.read_csv("./dates.csv")
 first_t = date(data.departure_ts)
 later_t = date(data.arrival_ts)


 diff = later_t - first_t
 print(diff)
```

Here you can find some exemple of data that I use

```
departure_ts            arrival_ts
2017-10-13 14:00:00+00  2017-10-13 20:10:00+00
2017-10-13 13:05:00+00  2017-10-14 06:55:00+00
2017-10-13 13:27:00+00  2017-10-14 21:24:00+00
2017-10-13 13:27:00+00  2017-10-14 11:02:00+00
```

Comment: So, what's your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your date strings to `pandas.Timestamp` using [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), after which you can directly subtract:

```
delta = pd.to_datetime(df["arrival_ts"])-pd.to_datetime(df["departure_ts"])

>>> delta
0   0 days 06:10:00
1   0 days 17:50:00
2   1 days 07:57:00
3   0 days 21:35:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks for yout answer.
Can I ask you the signification of the -1 or -2 days in the result ?

Comment: @Ralass - I reversed the subtraction to have departure-arrival now. Should make more sense.